# Which site is suitable for questions about sending high-frequency analogue signals down audio cables?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

This is my first question that isn't about Ubuntu, Linux or software engineering.

First off, is this the correct site to ask this question you're reading right now?

Secondly, I want to know and learn *how* to measure the maximum amount of analogue information that can be sent down a mono line level audio cable.

Say, three [FM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation) [carriers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_wave), each with a frequency in the single-digit MHz range, modulated by an, often static, [DC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_current) voltage or an audio signal from 0 to 22 kHz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beside the Signal Processing, other possible targets are:

- https://electronics.stackexchange.com
- https://sound.stackexchange.com
- https://musicfans.stackexchange.com

Read their help page (always https://…./help ) before. Possibly some of them do not apply, it depends on the details of your question. Note, reading the help page is not enough, digging through years of meta archives is not feasible, so try & ask. Smaller betas and sites generally not used to earn money, are typically more inclusive.

Comment: @RoboJ1M You can also ask the question in multiple parts on multiple sites. (Never ask exactly the same, cross-posts are forbidden, but asking different questions are okay.) Typically, this makes the old boys of both sites itchy, but actually it is very useful to investigate the same problem from multiple viewpoints.

Comment: Excellent, thankyou for all the answers given. I have an idea to make the world's first polyphonic analogue modular synthesiser but only requiring 1 standard patch cable, regardless of the number of polys. Current systems use a system where the number of patch cables are proportional to the mindset of patch cables. 2 poly equals 2 cables and 6 poly equals 6 cables.

Comment: @RoboJ1M Wow! I think it was not created because analog people wants to create and hear physical things, directly. I think they do not develop FM multiplexing on the same reason that they do not use A/D converters and digital data transfer. They want to hear things as they are. The signal changes caused by the analog transfer and processing is not a quality loss for them, but an expected effect. :-) But I am not one of them, I feel somewhere similarly, but in a totally different topic (retrocomputing + linux).

Comment: I'm learning Software Defined Radios for work so attempt one will be with SDRs. That'll require AD/DA which does kind upset the 'analogishnesseses' of it. Is like to try to do it with an analogue multiplexer, no digital radios. I'm hoping for some analogue artifacts? Some real analogue distortion. Well, best of luck to the both of us, eh?

Answer (score 4):

> First off, is this the correct site to ask this question you're reading right now?

Yes

> Secondly, I want to know and learn how to measure the maximum amount of analogue information that can be sent down a mono line level audio cable.

My first thought is [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) may be the right place. But check their [help page](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) about on-topic questions to make sure.